# connect to local database in windows xp c# windows form

Tags: c#, windows-xp, local-database

I build my windows form application using c# and I use local db file mdf
my app work fine in my laptop win 10, but on another pc with xp it is not working and there is a problem with connecting to local db
this is my code

```
SqlConnection conn21 = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Autoco.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
        if (conn21.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            conn21.Open();
        }
```

On second pc I paste the mdf database to C directory but when I run the app it tells me there is a problem with this line

and this is my error message
[error message](https://www60.zippyshare.com/v/4prB0LYA/file.html)

Comment: _What_ problem? Please post the complete error message. My first guess would be you lack permissions on C:\ . Try to put it into a subdirectory or userdirectory or application-directory.

Comment: i use application directory but the whole app dont run

Comment: ok wait a minute i will past the error message

Comment: https://www60.zippyshare.com/v/4prB0LYA/file.html

Comment: [link](https://www60.zippyshare.com/v/4prB0LYA/file.html)

Comment: i upload a txt file please see it

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/22238438) your question accordingly. Updates in comments can (and will) get lost.

Comment: i edit my question

Comment: hey can u see the error message?

Comment: Can you please edit in the text. Clicking links is somewhat frowned upon.

Comment: i dont know how...its tell me the question most code

Comment: please see the link